# How to determine with which instance a HTML element has been created?

Tags: javascript, dom, instanceof

```
var myElement = function(){
     this.element = document.createElement('div');
}

var myNewElement = new myElement;
console.log(myNewElement instanceof myElement); //return true

var myDiv = myNewElement.element;
console.log(myDiv instanceof myElement); //return false
```

Is it ever possible to determine that myDiv has been created from myElement function?

Comment: Unless you assign a property to the element that somehow "marks" the object, no.

Comment: Would you suggest to store a reference to myElement somewhere, by example in a data-attribute of myDiv?

Comment: Why do you need to know that an element was created by a specific function?

Comment: to make it able to know if it can interact with another element around, and then load the interaction function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the same lines of what @Felix said,

How about something like this [using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes):

```
var myElement = function(){
    this.element = document.createElement('div');
    this.element.dataset.instanceof = myElement;
    //document.body.appendChild(this.element);
}

var myNewElement = new myElement;
console.log(myNewElement instanceof myElement); //return true

var myDiv = myNewElement.element;
console.log(myDiv.dataset.instanceof == myElement); //return true
```

Which would result in the HTML element looking like this (if `appendChild()` is uncommented):

```
<div data-instanceof="function (){
    this.element = document.createElement('div');
    this.element.dataset.instanceof = myElement;
    document.body.appendChild(this.element);
}"></div>
```

---

Or instead of assigning the whole function, use strings like this:

```
var myElement = function(){
    this.element = document.createElement('div');
    this.element.dataset.instanceof = "myElement";
}

var myNewElement = new myElement;
console.log(myNewElement instanceof myElement); //true

var myDiv = myNewElement.element;
console.log(myDiv.dataset.instanceof == "myElement"); //true
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Technically it answers the question, so I mark it resolved. But in my design, I will mixin this solution to make it more quiet for the user (proper code), by assigning random ID, mapping ID with class in a special  object, and use a custom CRUD (create/read/update/delete) system to query this object. Same fashion, but less code in template.